# Return rows where sum on a field amount is reached from MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-extensions

My knowledge of MySQL is basic. I want to build a query to return all rows when is reached that sum a given amount value

- given value: 1.20
- field to sum: amount
- order by expirydate

**table:**

```
id name     expirydate  amount
1  name1    11-08-16     0.20     
2  name2    10-08-16     1.50
3  name3    08-08-16     1.00
```

I need the result from id 3, 2 order by expiry date.

Comment: Could you explain more? Also state what is your expected output?

Comment: concept is i have recharged amount in my wallet, every wallet amount is expiry date , if i have used withdraw amount some value , so i want the minimum reached amount  of row id.

Comment: And what's the expected output? row id : `3,2` ?

Comment: expected from above table id 3,2 ok. i need how to build on query ? mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `MySQL user defined variables`

```
SET @n := 1.2;

SELECT 
 t.id,
 t.name,
 t.expirydate,
 t.amount
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    @bal := @bal + amount AS runningAmount,
    IF(@bal >= @n, @doneHere := @doneHere + 1 , @doneHere) AS whereToStop
    FROM table_amount
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @bal := 0.0 , @doneHere := 0) var
    ORDER BY expirydate
) AS t
WHERE t.whereToStop <= 1
```

See a <kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bb47/1/1)</kbd>

Comment: Raw query should work anywhere. I know nothing about joomla though

Comment: Sorry i need to modify query adding where userid,status ? how to build on query?

Comment: wow! out of no where you are giving two more fields right after giving the answer.

Comment: And I don't know where they belong

Comment: There's a nice way to express gratitude in stackoverflow by accepting the answer that works for you. It's a good practice indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, you can use the following loop to get all results from query. Query will get result and through while loop we can display all records.

```
   <?php
 $query =   mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE amount >= 1.2 ORDER BY expirydate");
while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $row['name'].' '.$row['amount'].' '.$row['expirydate'].'<br>';


      }
?>
```