# How to fetch rows from which sum of a single integer/float column sums upto a certain value

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I have a table. It has the following structure

**goods_receiving_items**

- id
- item_id
- quantity
- created_at

I am trying to fetch rows against which have the following conditions

- Has one item_id
- When the sum of the quantity column equals a certain value

So for example I have the following data

```
+----+---------+----------+------------+
| id | item_id | quantity | created_at |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
|  1 |       2 |       11 | 2019-10-10 |
|  2 |       3 |      110 | 2019-10-11 |
|  3 |       2 |       20 | 2019-11-09 |
|  4 |       2 |        5 | 2019-11-10 |
|  5 |       2 |        1 | 2019-11-11 |
+----+---------+----------+------------+
```

I have tried the following query:

```
SET @sum:= 0;
SELECT   item_id, created_at, (@sum:= @sum + quantity) AS SUM, quantity 
FROM     goods_receiving_items
WHERE    item_id = 2 AND @sum<= 6
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

If I don't use `ORDER BY`, then the query will give me ID '1'. But if I use `ORDER BY` it will return all the rows with `item_id = 2`.

What should be returned are IDs '5' and '4' exclusively in this order

I can't seem to resolve this and `ORDER BY` is essential to my task.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, I have made up the following query

```
SELECT 
t.id, t.quantity, t.created_at, t.sum
      FROM 
       ( SELECT 
          *,
          @bal := @bal + quantity AS sum,
          IF(@bal >= $search_number, @doneHere := @doneHere + 1 , @doneHere) AS whereToStop
            FROM goods_receiving_items
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @bal := 0.0 , @doneHere := 0) var
            WHERE item_id = $item_id
            ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS t
                    WHERE t.whereToStop <= 1
                    ORDER BY t.created_at ASC
```

In the above query, $search_number is a variable that holds the value that has to be reached. $item_id is the item we are searching against.

This will return all rows for which the sum of the column **quantity** makes up the required sum. The sum will be made with rows in descending order by created_at and then will be rearranged in ascending order.

I was using this query to calculate the cost when a certain amount of items are being used in an inventory management system; so this might help someone else do the same. I took most of the query from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38887893/4622670) here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You should use the order by on the resulting set 
you could do this using a subquery

```
  SET @sum:= 0;

  select t.* 
  from t (
    SELECT item_id
        , created_at
        , (@sum:= @sum + quantity) as sum
        , quantity 
    FROM goods_receiving_items
    WHERE item_id = 2 AND @sum<= 6
  ) t
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: This just sorts the result after the sum has been reached.
What I require is to calculate the sum starting from the latest row i.e. that has the largest 'created_at' value

Answer (score 0):

You should try an `INNER JOIN` with `SELECT min(created_at)` or `SELECT max(created_at)`

From MYSQL docs:

> ...the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by
>   adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after
>   values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the
>   server chooses.

The answers on the following might help in more detail: [MYSQL GROUP BY and ORDER BY not working together as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157034/mysql-group-by-and-order-by-not-working-together-as-expected)

Comment: Wouldn't this just fetch a single value from the table?